# Windows 2012 WSUS and Office 2016

Tags: wsus, microsoft-office

I have configured our existing Windows 2012 WSUS Server to get updates for Office 2016.

Till now I always did it like this:

1. Checked the product category for Office 2016 .
2. this downloaded on next sync the listing
3. I left this on unapproved until a client connected to the server
   and marked this unapproved update as needed
4. I approved as needed

I have now installed Office 2016 on a Windows 2012 Terminal Server, which is getting updates from the WSUS Server.

For some unknown reason it does not seem to get updates for Office 2016.

Is there some setting I forgot?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking at a case of https://support.office.com/en-us/article/install-office-updates-2ab296f3-7f03-43a2-8e50-46de917611c5 where Office pulls the updates directly from MS.

I had this problem where Server 2016 itself would not report requirements to WSUS because it was pulling directly from MS update. [Windows Server 2016 not updating through WSUS](https://serverfault.com/questions/857607/windows-server-2016-not-updating-through-wsus) solved my problem. Most specifically, the **Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > System > Internet Communication Management > Internet Communication Settings > Turn off access to all Windows Update features** GPO option.